# gunicorn call fails every 6th time

Tags: nginx, python, gunicorn

i have a bottle app that has an endpoint that gets a timeout every 5th or 6th time i hit it (in my case, i just refresh every second to replicate)

when it works successfully, it takes ~ 150ms to load (based on the reporting in the network tab in chrome)

because it regularly loads so fast, i don't think this is a timeout issue at all. where can i look to see why this is happening?

this is a gunicorn/nginx setup.

Answer (score 0):

i was using a sqlalchemy pool of 5 without returning them correctly back to the pool. on the 5th request, the pool is depleted. the subsequent request waits for a connection until it hangs out.

not a gunicorn/nginx problem.